# How save Inheritance class list as json in postgresql with jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, postgresql-json

For saving a list with json format in postgresql I use `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52` in Spring boot 2 as follow:

```
@Entity
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Profile {
    ...
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<String> locations;

    // getters & setters
}
```

With this, All things are OK and I can save locations as json in postgresql. But I want to save locations as class inheritance structure. The classes are as follow:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClass1.class, name = "subClass1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClass2.class, name = "subClass2")
})
public abstract class MyClass {
    private String name;
    // getters & setters
}
public class SubClass1 extends MyClass {
    private String prop;
    // getters & setters
}
public class SubClass2 extends MyClass {
    ...
}
public class LocationList extends ArrayList<MyClass>{}
```

Now I want to save this structure in a json from class Profile as somthing bellow:

```
public class Profile {
    ...
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private LocationList locations;

    // getters & setters
}
```

When I create an instance of Profile and without saving, return it to client, It's fine, but when I want to save to postgresql db, it occure error and error message is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypeBindings for
>   class LocationList with 1 type parameter: class expects 0

How can I fix it?